# Python Recursion Implementation

Tags: python, recursion, networkx

I am trying to use more recursion in Python as I am getting more experienced in the language. I am using networkx and trying to get all network connections from a node that is passed into the function (along with relationship data). I was able to get it to work using sets and 3 for loops (messy), and am trying to figure out how to use recursion to solve it more efficiently.

If someone could point me to where I'm going wrong or the how to set the base case etc... it would be appreciated.

REGULAR METHOD:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
nodes = ["Gur","Qing","Samantha","Jorge","Lakshmi","Jack","John","Jill"]
edges = [("Gur","Qing",{"source":"work"}),
         ("Gur","Jorge", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Samantha","Qing", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Jack","Qing", {"source":"work"}),
        ("Jorge","Lakshmi", {"source":"work"}),
        ("Jorge","Samantha",{"source":"family"}),
        ("Samantha","John", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Lakshmi","Jack", {"source":"family"}),
        ("Jack","Jill", {"source":"charity"}),
        ("Jill","John",{"source":"family"})]
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

def get_connections(graph,node,relationship):
    connections_bunches = graph.edges(nbunch=nodes, data=True)
    print("Conn Bunches", connections_bunches, len(connections_bunches))   # a list of edges that are tuples
    ##GET A LIST OF NODES\EDGES BASED ON RELATIONSHIP
    RelConnections = [i for i in connections_bunches if i[2]['source'] == relationship]  #creates list of edges that match relationship para
    ##USE SETS TO MAINTAIN UNIQUE NODES
    ConnectionSet = set()    # Should be: [John, Jill, Samantha, Qing, Jorge, Gur].
    FinalConnectionSet = ConnectionSet
    ReturnConnectionSet = FinalConnectionSet
    ##LOOP THROUGH THE RELATIONSHIP LIST ADDING TO SETs
    for i in RelConnections:
        node1 = i[0]
        node2 = i[1]
        if node1 == node or node2== node:
            ConnectionSet.add(node1)
            ConnectionSet.add(node2)
    for i in RelConnections:
        node1 = i[0]
        node2 = i[1]
        if node1 in ConnectionSet:
            FinalConnectionSet.add(node2)
        elif node2 in ConnectionSet:
            FinalConnectionSet.add(node1)
    for i in RelConnections:
        node1 = i[0]
        node2 = i[1]
        if node1 in FinalConnectionSet:
            ReturnConnectionSet.add(node2)
        elif node2 in FinalConnectionSet:
            ReturnConnectionSet.add(node1)
    return list(FinalConnectionSet)#ConnectionSet#size()
```

['John', 'Gur', 'Samantha', 'Jill', 'Qing', 'Jorge']

RECURSION ATTEMPT:

```
def get_connectionsRecursive(graph, node, relationship):
    #print(node+"\n"+relationship+'\n', graph.edges())
    edges = graph.edges(nbunch=nodes, data=True)
    print("EDGES\n", edges, "LEN\n", len(edges))

    node_connections_set = set()

    if len(edges) == 0: #base case, all edges have been processed

         return list(node_connections_set)

    else:
        for tup in edges:
            #print(tup[-1]['source'])
            if tup[-1]['source'] != relationship:
                #continue
                #print("SOURCE NOT FAMILY", tup)
                graph.remove_edge(tup[0],tup[1])
            elif node in tup:
                print("NODE FOUND!", tup)
                node_connections_set.add(tup[0])
                node_connections_set.add(tup[1])

                graph.remove_edge(tup[0], tup[1])

        get_connectionsRecursive(graph, node, relationship)

    print("NEW LEN", len(edges))
    return graph.edges(), node_connections_set
    #print(get_connections(G,'John','family'))

print(get_connectionsRecursive(G,'John','family'))
```

It seems I am doing a lot of extra processing and my recursive call keeps erroring out because the list len(edges) sticks at 4 (all non relationship data. Any insight is appreciated.

[('Gur', 'Jorge', {'source': 'family'}), ('Qing', 'Samantha', {'source': 'family'}), ('Samantha', 'Jorge', {'source': 'family'}), ('Lakshmi', 'Jack', {'source': 'family'})]

TIA

Comment: Why do you prefer recursion over iteration?

Comment: In Python, iteration is generally preferred over recursion. You should not strive to replace iterative solutions with recursive ones: there is no tail-call optimization in Python, function call overhead is relatively big, and there is a relatively shallow maximum recursion depth (1000). You can tinker with that depth, but it's asking for memory errors. That being said, sometimes recursion is the most natural way to express an algorithm, so it shouldn't be avoided *altogether*, but if you have a working solution, why replace it with recursion?

Comment: Thanks for the input. It just seemed to me this would be a good case for it (breaking complex problem down into simpler pieces to a completion). I understand recursion in regards to a numbers' factorial etc.. was just trying to implement it here. T